# How to Optimize rows of a term document matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, text-mining

Suppose a $n × m$ term document matrix **T**. I'm looking for algorithms (preferably in R) able to automaticaly reduce row number, so only relvant terms are part of **T**. For example it is easy to find algorithms that exclude terms that are occuring less than $x$ times in the corpus. But you have to specify the $x$. I could find the proper $x$ by running statistics (centiles, etc.), so I was wondering if some algorithms are computing the $x$.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a (very small) toy example to illustrate your question?

Comment: Finally I ended using removeSparseTerms.